# Clustered Index and Sorting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, clustered-index

If you run the following query, for example, the rows could come back in any order:

```
select *
from [table_a];
```

A clustered index sorts the table based on whatever column(s) you choose.

That being said, if I have a clustered index on `[column_a], [column_b], and [column_c]` and run the same query from above, will the data ALWAYS come back sorted based on that order since that's the order that the clustered index was created on?

**More clarification:**

If I add an `ORDER BY` clause on something not in the index, the execution plan will have a sort operator.

If I have an `ORDER BY` clause on all the columns used in the clustered index,  the execution plan will not have a sort operator.

That's why I asked this question in the first place.

Comment: A parallel scan, even of the clustered index, will come back in random order. And that's just the start of possible options

Comment: Please don't post [the same question on multiple SE sites](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/300508/1186).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: question is cross-posted [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/300508/1186).*

> if I have a clustered index on [column_a], [column_b], and [column_c] and run the same query from above, will the data ALWAYS come back sorted based on that order since that's the order that the clustered index was created on?

#### No.

SQL Server does not guarantee that it will return data in any order *unless you specify the order*. It is easy to prove things can go wrong by simply creating a covering, non-clustered index that leads on a different column:

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dfb928e364bd25d80a613582b084163b)

But things can go sideways in other ways, too, e.g. when parallelism or partitioning come into play and SQL Server re-assembles the data from different threads, or when the query gets more complex using joins or filters and a different plan other than a clustered index scan makes sense. Leaving off the order by clause is telling SQL Server: "I don't care about order."

Also, just as a point of clarification:

> If I have an ORDER BY clause on all the columns used in the clustered index, the execution plan will not have a sort operator.

...this is true only if the columns are listed in the exact same order as the key definition. `ORDER BY c, b, a` is "all the columns" but it obviously will produce different output (and require some type of sort operation to get there).

#### If you expect and want to be comfortable relying on a certain order, always use an ORDER BY clause.

Further reading:

- [No Seatbelt - Expecting Order without ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by) (Conor Cunningham)
- [Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120507062947/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx) (Alexander Kuznetsov)
- [T-SQL Tuesday #56: SQL Server Assumptions](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions) (me - see #3)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Relying on undocumented behavior](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior) (also me)
- [Why is SSMS inserting new rows at the top of a table not the bottom?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5774/1186) (dba.se question)

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb for SQL reporting is that if you expect the result set to be in a certain order, then you *always* need to add the appropriate `ORDER BY` clause.  Now, it is possible that SQL Server might choose to scan the index in the order of `column_a`, `column_b` and `column_c`, and therefore return the results in that order, but there is no *guarantee* that this would happen.  But, if you used the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [table_a]
ORDER BY [column_a], [column_b], [column_c];
```

then an index on the three columns, in the same order as the above `ORDER BY` clause should be used and would be said to *cover* the entire query.